# Greybox no overlay

Tags: php, javascript, greybox

How can you prevent an overlay in greybox?

I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var GB_ROOT_DIR = "greybox/";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Comment: ok , where is the event that shows the greybox ?

Comment: <a rel="gb_page_center[250, 100]" href="my_page.php">My page</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the css, you need to remove

```
#GB_overlay {
background-color: #000;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 100;
}
```

In order to remove the overlay

Comment: Thanks for your answer... it helped me figure out the solution... i have not removed the entire style, but i have commented out the background-color attribute in the above style and it is working well now. :)